# Bit Size of GHC's Int Type

Tags: haskell, types, size, ghc

Why is GHC's Int `type` not guaranteed to use exactly 32 bits of precision? [This document claim](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Int.html#t%3aInt) it has *at least* 30-bit signed precision. Is it somehow related to fitting `Maybe Int` or similar into 32-bits?

Comment: There will be others with more details, but I think it has to do with garbage collection and laziness.  A bit for "is evaluated", a bit for copied by GC.  Not 100% sure though.

Comment: If you need to have 32 bits guaranteed, there's the `Int32` type in `Data.Int`.

Comment: There is no upper bound because it depends on the platform: on 64x machine `Prelude.ma­xBound :: Int` should be around 2^63

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is to allow implementations of Haskell that use tagging.  When using tagging you need a few bits as tags (at least one, two is better).  I'm not sure there currently are any such implementations, but I seem to remember Yale Haskell used it.

Tagging can somewhat avoid the disadvantages of boxing, since you no longer have to box everything; instead the tag bit will tell you if it's evaluated etc.

Comment: Could you please explain "tagging" and "boxing"?

Answer (score 15):

The Haskell language definition states that the [type `Int` covers at least the range [−2<sup>29</sup>, 2<sup>29</sup>−1]](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/basic.html#sect6.4).
There are other compilers/interpreters that use this property to boost the execution time of the resulting program.

All internal references to (aligned) Haskell data point to memory addresses that are multiple of 4(8) on 32-bit(64-bit) systems. So, references need only 30bits(61bits) and therefore allow 2(3) bits for *"pointer tagging"*.

In case of data, the GHC uses those tags to store information about that referenced data, i.e. whether that value is already evaluated and if so which constructor it has.

In case of 30-bit `Int`s (so, not GHC), you could use one bit to decide if it is either a pointer to an unevaluated `Int` or that `Int` itself.

Pointer tagging could be used for *one-bit reference counting*, which can speed up the garbage collection process. That can be useful in cases where a direct one-to-one producer-consumer relationship was created at runtime: It would result directly in memory reuse instead of a garbage collector feeding.

So, using 2 bits for pointer tagging, there could be some wild combination of intense optimisation...
In case of Ints I could imagine these 4 tags:

- a singular reference to an unevaluated `Int`
- one of many references to the same possibly still unevaluated `Int`
- 30 bits of that `Int` itself
- a reference (of possibly many references) to an evaluated 32-bit `Int`.

Comment: @hvr: I'm not sure why I remembered 28bits; the Haskell 98 Report states the same range as the 2010. Thx for the correction.

Comment: I've revised everything. Completely new text, more precise than before.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is because of early ways to implement GC and all that stuff. If you have 32 bits available and you only need 30, you could use those two spare bits to implement interesting things, for instance using a zero in the least significant bit to denote a value and a one for a pointer.

Today the implementations don't use those bits so an `Int` has at least 32 bits on GHC. (That's not entirely true. IIRC one can set some flags to have 30 or 31 bit `Int`s)